# How to remove the yellow stains from my teeth?

Tags: dentistry, coloration-discoloration, removal, brushing-teeth, bleach-teeth-whitening

How to remove the yellow stains from my teeth?

I brush two times a day once in the morning and once in  the night.But I am still having yellow stains in my teeth.The back side of two of my teeth have also turned brown.

I have also brushed with baking powder for 3-4 days but no result came .

What should I do to get natural color of my teeth back?Please help.

Comment: try to check and see if anything you are using for your oral health can cause teeth staining.
my periodontal mouthwash can (and has before) cause brown stains.

Could also be anything else you put in your mouth.

Comment: What caused the yellow stains? Smoking? Tea? Coffee? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few aspects that need to be addressed.

1) **Diet & Oral habits**: Often, drinks with natural or artificial coloring will stain the surface of the enamel and any tartar (calcified plaque) that rests on your tooth. Some oral products (ex: smoking) and medication (ex: some mouthrinces and some antibiotics) are also known to cause discoloration.  Any long-term solutions will require you to examine the cause of the coloration, and whether there are underlying causes for it (a more in-depth look at teeth coloration can be fond here: [1](http://www.nature.com/bdj/journal/v190/n6/full/4800959a.html)).

2) **Cleaning and scaling**: A dental health professional can remove the tartar and remove external coloration. This procedure has to be performed every 6-12 months if not more often, depending on that professional's assessment of your current health [2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4555792/).

3) **Chemical treatment** If all external coloration has been removed, and you are still dissatisfied with your tooth color, a dentist can assess and prescribe you a whitening agent, or otherwise recommend an off the shelf solution but this is beyond the scope of the original question.

Sources:

1. http://www.nature.com/bdj/journal/v190/n6/full/4800959a.html
2. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4555792/

Answer (score -4):

**Salt :**

Salt is one of the fundamental dental cleansing agents that has been used for ages. It helps replenish lost mineral content in the teeth and helps revive their white color.

You can use common salt regularly each morning as a tooth powder instead of toothpaste. Another option is to mix common salt with charcoal and brush your teeth with it regularly.
You can also mix common salt with baking soda and gently rub it on your teeth.
Be extra careful using salt as it can cause damage to your gums and tooth enamel if used roughly.

**Lemon :**

The bleaching property present in lemons can also help get rid of yellow discoloration. In fact, gargling with lemon juice and scrubbing your teeth with lemon peel is one of the best ways to make your teeth white again.

Mix together a few drops of lemon juice and some salt.
Apply the mixture on the stained teeth and rub the paste vigorously over your teeth and gums. Leave it on for a few minutes and then rinse your mouth thoroughly with water.
Do this twice daily for about two weeks to get rid of tartar and the yellow tinge.

**Orange Peel :**

Cleaning your teeth with fresh orange peel on a regular basis will reduce the yellow tinge accumulated on your teeth.

Rub orange peel over your teeth every night before going to sleep. The vitamin C and calcium in the orange peel will combat the microorganisms throughout the night.
Do this for a few weeks and you will notice effective results.
If fresh orange peel is not available, you can use dried orange peel powder.

**Strawberries :**

Strawberries contain a good amount of vitamin C, which helps make your teeth whiter.

*Home remedy for yellow teeth*

Grind a few strawberries into a paste. Rub the paste on your teeth gently. If done twice daily for a few weeks, the yellow tinge on your teeth will vanish.
Another option is to mix the pulp of one strawberry with one-half teaspoon of baking soda and spread the mixture onto your teeth and let it sit for a few minutes. Rinse out your mouth and brush your teeth with toothpaste to get rid of any residue.

***Reference :***

http://www.top10homeremedies.com/home-remedies/home-remedies-for-yellow-teeth.html

Comment: Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that **all answers** should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].

Comment: www.top10homeremedies.com is not a very good source...

Comment: And using any of the fruits will actually demineralize the enamel, making it white temporarily, but in the long run will cause loss of enamel, cavitation and sensitivity.